# Update Trigger won't trigger two statements

Tags: sql-server

I added a two update statement to a trigger FOR UPDATE, but the column won't update, not sure what I did wrong. See the example of the two statement below.

Table `Relationship`

```
 Update Profile 
 Set LDR = 1
 From inserted, Profile
 Where inserted.TARGET_ID = profile.ID  
   And inserted.RELATION_TYPE = 'LEADER'

 Update Profile
 Set LDR = 0
 From Deleted, Profile
 Where Deleted.Target_ID = profile.ID 
   And Deleted.RELATION_TYPE = 'LEADER'
```

**Profile** table:

```
  ID      | LDR |
  --------+-----+
  4658632 |  0  |
```

**Relationship** table:

```
TARGET_ID | Relation_TYPE
----------+--------------
 4658632  | LEADER
```

If there is a record inserted in the relationship table where Relation_TYPE Equal LEADER then Update Profile Table Column LDR to 1. Same for the reverse.

Is there anything missing?

Thank you

Comment: *"Is there anything missing? "* `JOIN` syntax? [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: Nope. the join is there From inserted, profile where inserted.target_id = profile.id

Comment: I stand by my point. It's 2018, not 1989. 

Comment: You have a cross join converted to an inner join. Yes it works but the ANSI-92 style join syntax has been around now for more than 25 years. Time to change your coding style. Also, it is possible from looking at your code that it updates the same column twice.

Comment: @SeanLange I think it's actually a double cartesian. They have `Profile` in the `UPDATE` clause, and then `inserted` and `Profile` in the `FROM` clause. The 2 `Profile` objects would actually be treated as 2 different instances of the table. @ the OP, you should really be using Aliases too: `UPDATE A SET Col1 = i.col FROM inserted I JOIN [Table] A ON A.id = i.ID;`

Comment: If the RELATION_TYPE is LEADER in the table prior to the update it will ALWAYS become 0 after your trigger runs. I suspect that is not what you are intending to do. What would really help is to see the ddl for the Profile table with some sample data. Here is a great article on how to put that together. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: What do you intend should happen if Relation_Type = 'Leader' both before and after the update?

Comment: @Larnu it isn't a double Cartesian since the table Profile isn't aliased, thus its full name is the alias-equivalent. That said, implied joins using the WHERE clause are definitely something that should be avoided.

Comment: Tried Aliases, and used inner join instead. also removed the second update, non of those updated the column.

Comment: @Sean Lange the record get created with the LEADER in the RELATION_TYPE Column.

Comment: See my updated post for more clarification.

Comment: You are missing my point. Your row is being updated twice. It first gets changed from  0 to 1 in the first update. But then the second update runs and sets it back to 0.

Comment: How about if you share the trigger code you have and the update statement you are running?

Comment: The row doesn't exist. it's a new insert and it get deleted if not needed it doesn't stay there. so the update will be like if row exist update LDR to 1 if Row doesn't exist update LDR to 0. hope this clear it up.

Comment: Clear as mud. Again, can you share the trigger code? I don't even understand which table it is on. And the rules here are incredibly confusing. There is no delete in your trigger code so not sure what the delete you are talking about it. Do yourself a favor and post the actual details. I asked originally about 3 hours ago. My guess is that once you post the details so your question is clear this will take about 10-15 minutes.

Comment: It sounds like you have an UPDATE trigger on Relationship and are running the UPDATE against Profile. You then say if a record is "inserted in the relationship table where Relation_TYPE Equal LEADER", which would not be covered in an UPDATE trigger. Also, as others have mentioned, UPDATE will create the new instance of the rows affected in the INSERTED table and the old instance of the rows in the DELETED table. It sounds like you need to define some business logic, or provide a timestamp column to track which change takes precedence.

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off writing it like this: (**edited**)

```
update 
    p
set
    LDR = case profile.ID when inserted.TARGET_ID then 1 else 0 end
from 
    Profile p
    left join inserted i on
        i.TARGET_ID = p.ID  
    left join deleted d on
        d.TARGET_ID = p.ID
where
    (
        i.RELATION_TYPE = 'LEADER' or
        d.RELATION_TYPE = 'LEADER'
    );
```

Or a safer approach that ensures no ambiguity in what's getting updated:

```
with cte
as  (
    select
        ID,
        [LDR] = 1
    from
        Profile p
        inner join inserted i on
            i.TARGET_ID = p.ID
    where
        i.RELATION_TYPE = 'LEADER'
        union all
    select
        ID,
        [LDR] = 0
    from
        Profile p
        inner join deleted d on
            d.TARGET_ID = p.ID
    where
        d.RELATION_TYPE = 'LEADER'
    )
update
    p
set
    LDR = cte.LDR
from
    Profile p
    inner join cte on 
        p.ID = cte.ID;
```

Comment: This still doesn't check for UPDATE conditions, and could set both 1 and 0 values.

Comment: While you are correct, the OP didn't provide any information on the data structures that the inserted and deleted tables represent. As such, I can't provide guidance on what counts as a real update and what doesn't. For example, CHECKSUM(i.*) != CHECKSUM(d.*) could work on a table that isn't using a rowversion or last update column, otherwise you could use the rowversion equivalent to check for the identity of the row.

Comment: I Added Example and Syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Conditional testing is missing. If these are in the same UPDATE trigger, then on an actual update to a record, there will be values in both *inserted* and *deleted*. To fix this, try:

```
WITH Updates AS (
    SELECT IsNull(i.Target_ID, d.Target_ID) as Target_ID,
    CASE
        WHEN i.Target_ID IS NULL
            THEN 0
        ELSE 1
    END as value
    FROM (
        SELECT Target_ID
        FROM inserted
        WHERE RELATION_TYPE = 'LEADER'
        ) as i

    FULL OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT Target_ID
        FROM deleted
        WHERE RELATION_TYPE = 'LEADER'
        ) as d
    ON i.Target_ID = d.Target_ID
    ) u
Update Profile 
    Set LDR = value
FROM Profile p
INNER JOIN Updates u
    ON p.Target_ID = u.Target_ID
```

Comment: Are you saying to put this code in the trigger? whats the Updates stand for? won't work